# Css hover with box shadow is not working as i required

Tags: html, css

```html
<style>
.ui-state-active {
  color: #fff;
  background:red;
  #box-shadow: inset -7px 7px 9px -7px #236c4d;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
.ui-state-active:hover{
 box-shadow: inset 15px 7px 9px -7px #fff;
 box-shadow: inset -7px 7px 9px -7px #fff;
}
</style>
<div class="ui-state-active">18
</div>
```

I need something like this, when i hovered on a div it show a transformed triangle on top right like shown in image, I just explained my requirement as image for clear clarification[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with pseudo elements `:before` or `:after`

```css
.ui-state-active {
  color: #fff;
  background:red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position: relative;
}
.ui-state-active:hover:after{
  content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 3px;
    border: solid 10px white;
    border-color: white white transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-state-active">18
</div>
```

Comment: Mr. z0mBi3 You are awesome, Thank U bro

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a box-shadow, I'd use a pseudo-element.

There's a couple of way to do that.

---

**1.** A position, rotated pseduo-element:

```css
span {
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f00;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 3em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
  top: -100%;
  left: 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0%, 0%);
  transition: transform .35s ease;
}
span:hover::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0%, 50%)
```

```html
<span>16</span>
```

---

**2.** Alternatively, a psuedo-element made entirely of borders

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f00;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 3em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: orange orange transparent transparent;
  border-width: 0px;
  transition: border-width .35s ease;
}
div:hover::after {
  border-width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div>16</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, :)

***HTML***

```
<div class="date">
   <div class="sideflip"></div>
    18
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.date
{
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:65px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  background:red;
  color:#ffffff;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.sideflip
{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  font-size:1px;
  position:absolute;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-50deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
  margin-left:160px;
  margin-top:-130px;
  background:#ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.date:hover .sideflip
{
   margin-left:60px;
  margin-top:-30px;
}
.date:hover
{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

[image: Here is the Snap]